# Problem when using a Breakpoint in ListView Listener

Tags: java, eclipse

I’m using eclipse on Ubuntu (Version: Oxygen.3a Release 4.7.3a Build id: 20180405-1200) for a Java project. I have a problem with breakpoints. If I set a breakpoint in a ListView Listener, the breakpoint is hit when I click on an item of the list but everything then gets frozen. I mean **the whole machine is frozen** (not only eclipse).

I then have to use another machine to do an ssh connection. I can then kill the application and then I get the hand back.

I have noticed this problem with ListView Listeners (I don’t know for other Listeners). If I set a breakpoint in an ordinary function, it works and I can use the “step into” or “step over” buttons.

Do you know what could be wrong?

Thanks